# Strange String concatenation in list

Tags: dart

This tests passes but the behavior is rather unexpected

Note the missing comma between "foo" "bar"

```dart
test("concatenation", (){

  List<String> test = ["foo" "bar"];
  expect(test.first, equals( "foobar"));

});
```

I would have expected a syntax error at

```dart
List<String> test = ["foo" "bar"];
```

not the concatenation of "foo" and "bar"

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature. Ajacent strings are concatenated automatically by Dart.

```dart
List<String> test = ["foo" "bar"];
```

is the same as

```dart
List<String> test = ["foobar"];
```

See also http://dartbug.com/14139 for an open feature request to help finding such bugs.

Comment: Thanks, that was a fast responce. Its a very odd feature!

Comment: It might be nice for splitting long string literals in multiple lines.

Comment: This is a language feature that developed from an early decision in the language to remove the + operator from Strings. To avoid things like "5" + 5 or 5 + "5" and the strange gotchas that occur in JS. Adjacent strings became automatically concated for long multiline strings. Later the + operator was re-introduced with specific typing but the original functionality remains

Comment: It's not all that odd, or at least not without precedent, as C/C++ and Python both do it.